# Strange ArcSDE error inserting null into state_locks?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, oracle-dbms, versioning

I'm working with a heavily customized version of ArcMap 9.3.1. It's heavily customized, but it mostly uses class extensions and special validations.

Environment:

- ArcSDE installed in: linux, red-hat, version 9.3.1, no service packs;
- Oracle 10g;
- Versioned database, moving edits to base, single DEFAULT version;
- ArcMap connecting via direct connection;

I have an user, creating simple points using a custom tool we made. This tool basically fires other actions, but nothing too deep. The user, after a while, creating points (simple points!) get's a weird database message, specifying:

> > ORA-01400
> >
> > Cannot insert null into sde.state_locks.sde_id
> >
> > [sde.default][state_id]=6935

After this any point he creates fails, with the same message.

Anyone has a clue of what is happening? Has anyone ever see this?

Just to be clear, the error is intermitent. The tool we made works just fine, with unit tests and everything.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with orphans as describe in this article: [Getting Rid of Orphan State Locks in SDE with Oracle](http://cggis.wordpress.com/2011/08/).

Comment: Master Kirk! THank you for answering the question. Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with the locks itself, since I can compress the database to state zero. :(

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you may have lost your connection, or at least something tried to free it.  I don't know of a different way to get your SDE_ID to null.  Can you perform any other actions?

I would check the log files to see if there is there are any errors prior to this.  You could also try to run an SDE Intercept or trace.

Comment: Hi travis! Well, the logs do not show anything, but it's weird. We moved back to service connection and we've been getting a few Network IO errors, typical of that issue. i'm still investigating.

Comment: When you get the network IO errors, is your connection's gsrvr process still running on the server machine?